# Symfony project not working on Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I'm following the instructions from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world) 
in order to deploy a symfony project in Google App Engine, but the hello world example is not working in my local computer using Google App Engine Launcher neither in the cloud (it is working in a localhost with XAMPP).

The app.yaml file is:

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
application: myprojectid
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /clear_cache
  script: clear_cache.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: web/app.php

env_variables:
  CACHE_DIR: "gs://#default#/symfony/cache"
  LOG_DIR: "gs://#default#/symfony/log"
```

The config_prod.yml file is:

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

#framework:
#    validation:
#        cache: apc

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: null
        port: null
        dbname: hello
        user: root
        password: null
        unix_socket: /cloudsql/myprojectid:helloworldinstance
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc

# Force monolog to use syslog
monolog:
    handlers:
        syslog:
            type: syslog
            level: debug
```

The log from launcher throw this:

```
2015-08-24 19:59:38 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\symfony-standard']"
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:43,378 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:43,608 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54278
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:43,612 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:43,615 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:46,928 module.py:808] default: "HEAD /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/symfony/cache/classes.map HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:46,954 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=1000&prefix=symfony%2Fcache%2Fclasses.map HTTP/1.1" 200 139
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:46,983 module.py:808] default: "HEAD /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/symfony/cache/appProdProjectContainer.php HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,010 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=1000&prefix=symfony%2Fcache%2FappProdProjectContainer.php HTTP/1.1" 200 139
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,036 module.py:808] default: "HEAD /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/symfony/cache HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,073 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=1000&prefix=symfony%2Fcache HTTP/1.1" 200 203
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,128 module.py:808] default: "POST /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/_ah_is_writable_temp_file HTTP/1.1" 201 -
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,160 module.py:808] default: "HEAD /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket/symfony/log HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,181 module.py:808] default: "GET /_ah/gcs/app_default_bucket?delimiter=%2F&max-keys=1000&prefix=symfony%2Flog HTTP/1.1" 200 201
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:

stdout:

Status: 500 Internal Server Error


X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26


Content-type: text/html







INFO     2015-08-24 19:59:47,573 module.py:808] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

It seems that is a problem with permissions of cache and log folders, but i'm not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the Google App Engine default bucket in Cloud Storage was created?

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/setup

I suggest adding the following static handlers to your `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: web/favicon.ico
  upload: web/favicon.ico

- url: /bundles
  static_dir: web/bundles
```

Comment: Thanks. The hello world example worked in the cloud with your suggestions. But when trying to upload a regular project there was a error. It seems that Google App Engine Launcher can´t upload projects with more than 10000 files. I tried to deploy from a repository following the following guides    https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-hosted-repository  and  https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy , but although the files are uploaded to Google App Engine , the project did not work. Are there any workaround for the 10000 files limit?

Comment: That's another issue, I suggest moving static files to cloud storage or even moving some PHP libraries as well with this `google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets` directive in your php.ini file  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/advanced#using_php_include_and_require